# Prevent spring-boot-devtools from shutting down HSQL (server mode)

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb

I use Spring Boot 1.3.8.RELEASE and `spring-boot-devtools` together with HSQL in server mode:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/dbname
```

Unforunately, `spring-boot-devtools` seems to `SHUTDOWN` the database server when the application exits (or the application context is refreshed). Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8702) in `spring-boot-devtools` that was fixed in Spring Boot v1.4.6.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the hsqldb server separately from your spring boot application?

I have a similar setup.  I launch the hsqldb server first using a command like...

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:c:\temp\hsqldbserver --dbname.0 ops
```

Then in my spring boot application.yml, i have my datasource configured like so...

```
spring:
  datasource: 
    driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    url: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/ops
    username: SA
    password:
```

Shutting down spring boot should have no impact on the hsqldb server which is running in a separate jvm.

Comment: This is exactly my setup, too. So I digged a little deeper and as it turns out, this unwanted behaviour seems to be caused by `spring-boot-devtools` ([in DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L107)), which I am also using. Even when packaging the application and running via `java -jar`, the `SHUTDOWN` is sent to the HSQL server.

Comment: Executing `SHUTDOWN` requires admin privileges. Therefore you should create a non-admin user after starting the server and connect from Spring with this new user. The `SHUTDOWN` from Spring will then fail.